# changing the datatables css for sorting for custom css

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using `datatables` and want to replace the sorting with the custom sorting icons which looks like below

https://prnt.sc/1x3yeoo

any idea how can i do it, i tried using the background image no repeat but it does not work that and major problem is how i align one to the right side and other to the left side

this is my try

```
<table>
<th>id <span class="icon_arrow_left"></span><span class="icon_arrow_right"></span>
<table>
```

but i am confused how can i move to the left side and another to the right side

i had already done `background:none;` to existing sorting

Comment: Span elements are not block elements, you need to set them as block elements and set width and height for the background image to appear.  Also, can we get your CSS, HTML alone does not explain much?

Comment: by block elements you mean div

Comment: There are main 3 types. Inline (span, b, center, etc) which do not take height or width properties and are supposed to be text styling. Block (div, p, h1, etc) which takes up the entire row if permitted and forces other block elements in a new row. Inline-block, which is a mix of both, but takes width and height, but floats with text and other inline and inline-block elements. You would need to use it as an inline-block in your case to display a background image.